# If $s=a+b+c,p=ab+bc+ac, r=abc, s^2-2p+r=4$ and $a,b,c>0,$ prove that $2sp+15r^2\geq 33r$

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $s=a+b+c$,$p=ab+bc+ac$, $r=abc$, $s^{2}-2p+r=4$ and $a,b,c>0,$

prove that $$2sp+15r^{2}\geq 33r.$$
I tried to use some inequalities from [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2426h1034364_a2b2c2abc4_and_its_consequences), but nothing works. Suggestions ?

Comment: Please use MathJax and write the equations in the text, not in the title.

Comment: s is a+b+c. Sorry, I edited.

Comment: Use the MathJax [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the equations.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Okay, thank you.

Comment: Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b,c \gt 0$ and $s=a+b+c$,$p=ab+bc+ac$, $r=abc$

This looks like the coefficient of some polynomial in $x$, where $ x \in \{ a,b,c \} $
$$x^3-sx^2+px-r = 0$$
From $s^2-2p+r=4$ , say $ r =4+ 2p-s^2$
$$2sp+15r^2 \geq 33r$$
$$2sp+15(4+2p-s^2)^2 - 33(4+2p-s^2) \geq 0$$
$$ 15s^4-60ps^2-87s^2+2ps+60p^2+174p+108 \geq 0$$
Noticing the number of positive constant, you can substitute back the value of $s$ and $p$, Or use that fact that $x^3-sx^2+px-4-2p+s^2= 0$, where $ x \in \{ a,b,c  \} $ to reduce the problem by removing powers of $s$ or $p$ and finish it up
$$ 15s^4+2ps+60p^2+174p+108 \geq 60ps^2+87s^2$$

Comment: You mean substitute s and p with the their components a,b,c ? This looks bads. I tried too many substitution, but calculations look bad, so I gave up. Are you sure that this is work? If I will start to do this ugly calculations, I want to be sure that this is a good method. Or you can show me a complete proof ?

Comment: The inequality already looks true, since $a,b,c \gt 0$ , then $ p \gt s $

Comment: That is not true. Is $s>=p$. For a proof, see the above link.

Comment: If you look at the inequality, if $s \ge p$,  look at the powers and size, for positive $p,s$ and compare the right hand side with the left hand side, you'll know if it's true or not

Comment: Comparing them is the point, but how?
I don't think solving an inequality is as simple as you say.The inequality is true and I want to prove it, but just looking at the size is not enough.Eventually to use this reaching an interesting decomposition and using something that results from the initial condition such as $ a + b + c <= 3 $, etc.Intuitively, anyone can look at it and say it's true, RHS looks bigger than LHS, but I need proof. Plus you contradict yourself, because at first you said it seemed true because $ s <p $ and now you use $ s> = p $. I'm sorry if I was mean.